# HTTP Error 500: localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm running into an HTPP Error 500 and I'm not sure why. When I start my service, I pop open a Chrome browser and navigate to `http://localhost:5000`, and the error pops up. The Chrome Developer Tools windows shows this single error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:5000/
```

Here is my Startup.cs file (exluding using statements for simplicity):

```
namespace Tuner
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);

                                var host = new WebHostBuilder()
               .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
               .UseKestrel()
               .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")
               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .UseIISIntegration()
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();
            host.Run();
        }


        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //Setup Logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Trace()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .CreateLogger();
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            //.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen();

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            });


            lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
            {
                Log.Debug("Application Stopping. Do stuff.");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

With MVC, this causes the HomeController Index method to get called:

```
namespace Tuner.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string appVersion = typeof(HomeController).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
        public string appName = "Empty Web App";

        [HttpGet("/")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var url = Request.Path.Value;
            if (url.EndsWith(".ico") || url.EndsWith(".map"))
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(404);
            }
            else
            {
                // else block is reached
                return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
        }

        [HttpGetAttribute("app/version")]
        public string Version()
        {
            return appVersion;

        }

        [HttpGetAttribute("app/name")]
        public string ProjectName()
        {
            return appName;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Index.cshtml file (which has been placed in Views/Home):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tuner";
}

@section pageHead {
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/vendor.bundle.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/main.bundle.js"></script>

}

<cache vary-by="@Context.Request.Path">
    <app>Loading content...</app>
</cache>
```

Comment: what is the 500 Error ? Are you logging errors some where or is there something in eventvwr ?

Comment: There is most likely an exception being thrown in your code somewhere, which is caught by ASP.Net framework and then it in turn returns a HTTP Code 500 (Internal Server Error) response to the browser. Debug the application and see where the exception is being thrown then let us know the details.

Comment: The 500 error shows up in the web browser and Chrome Developer Tools console.

Answer (score 34):

I got the following error hosing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application on IIS 10.0 after following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

```
This page isn't working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

[image]

If you are on Windows:

Start Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application.

[image]

In my case I had the error below and could continue from there (Allow my Application Pool User to access localdb).

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
> -Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Comment: I was able to use the Event Viewer to know the actual error the page is throwing. In my own case, object serialization.

Comment: Although I had a different error, looking at the event view pointed me to the fact that I had  the error: "Attribute 'processPath' is required" due to an issue in my web.config file.

Answer (score 20):

You, like me, might need to install ASP.NET!

On Windows Server 2012 R2 this can be done via the *Turn Windows features on or off* feature:

1. Complete the *Before You Begin*, *Installation Type*, and *Server Selection* steps of the wizard.
2. Under *Server Roles*, find the *Web Server (IIS)* node and expand it.
3. Expand the *Web Server* node.
4. Expand the *Application Development* node.
5. Check the *ASP.NET 3.5* or *ASP.NET 4.5* nodes, as appropriate.
6. Finish the *Add Roles and Features Wizard*.

Answer (score 4):

In your setup the UseIISIntegration "interferes" with UseUrls, as the UseUrls setting is for the Kestrel process and not the IISExpress/IIS.

If you want to change the IIS Port, have a look at Properties/launchSettings.json - there you can configure the applicationUrl IIS is using.

You could remove the UseIISIntegration for testing purposes and then you can connect to Port 5000, but you **never** should use Kestrel as Internet facing Server, it should always be run behind a Reverse Proxy like IIS or Nginx, etc.

See [the Hosting Docs Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

I was using IIS (I'm unclear if OP was trying to use IIS), but I did not **Install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle**, as described in [instructions like this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis). After installing that Module, my app served  (i.e. no 500 error)

Answer (score 1):

Run asp.net MVC core 1.1 project in vs2017 also get this error.
Solved by upgrade all NuGet Packages version 1.x to latest 2.x and target framework to .NET Core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check database once. In my condition I got issue in asp boilerplate. VS17 .net sdk version 2.2 . just change in app setting file and add any working database and try to run project again.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that you're trying to pass a PageModel as a parameter. For some reason, that fails:

*System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionary' on 'GT.ADS.Web.Pages.Error1Model.TempData' is not supported.*

That should be common enough if you try to migrate from standard MVC architecture into Blazor setup. After I passed what I needed from the model, the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows .NET Hosting bundle has that the .NET runtime. Make sure to install the same version that runs your application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You have .NET Core 6.0 or Above,

Just Install these two packages from Nuget:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

After that Add the Following Line in your program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Also, Add (only if missing)

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.DocumentTitle = "Your API";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Your API V1");
});
```

Now Remove Your Project(s) bin, and obj folders, and clean & rebuild your solution after that try to publish, Host your project on the server.

Answer (score -2):

For Google Chrome:

- Open your browser and enter "chrome://flags" in the address bar.
- Search for "insecure" in the search bar. Find the option "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" and set it
  to "Enabled".
- Restart your browser.

For Mozilla Firefox:

- Open your browser and enter "about:config" in the address bar.
- Accept the warning message that says "This might void your
  warranty!".
- Search for "insecure" in the search bar.
- Set the "network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist" option to
  "false".
- Restart your browser.

After making these changes, I hope your browser will no longer automatically redirect "http://localhost:8081" to HTTPS and your application will work directly over HTTP. However, please note that browsers can change these behaviors with security updates, so keep in mind that these settings may change in the future.

The reason why this solution is applied is that the browser's default behavior is to enforce HTTPS connections for security reasons. However, in your case, your application only supports HTTP on "http://localhost:8081" and does not have a valid HTTPS certificate. By modifying the browser's settings, you are instructing it not to automatically redirect to HTTPS and allow connections over HTTP, resolving the issue.

It's important to note that this solution is not recommended for production environments, as HTTPS is crucial for securing sensitive data in transit. It should only be used for local development purposes when you don't have a valid HTTPS certificate.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since your answer appears likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: One major problem that I see here is that either you or ChatGPT completely missed the point of the question.  The question obviously isn't about how to solve the issue in a single user's browser, but rather how to solve the *backend* problem.

Comment: in my case, it happend after updating windows 10 to 11, it is a default for w11 so you need do that if that same for you, I added here because I didn't find anywhere any solution about that

Comment: iis is always redirects http to https so you are not able to connect to HTTP if you didnt set your browser like that, if you want to see I can share my screen this is a solution for that

Comment: if you want to remove this yes I can, but I added it here for if someone need that, maybe it will not solve if it is a ssl problem on your backend, it will make wider understanding about that