# Unable to use MVC Controller with ASP.Net Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

**What I have so far (that works)**

I have an ASP.Net Web API 2 project. Well, at least that's what I remember creating when I set up the project, I am not sure how to confirm that.

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and .Net Framework version 4.6.

In terms of the API side of things, this is all working great. The API controllers are fine, I can get data, post data, etc.

Just a bit of additional information in case it matters, I have added SignalR to the project which has been configured.

As it may be important, here are my various configuration files:

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**What I am trying to do (that doesn't work)**

However, I want to add a HTML page so the user can view some information (just static HTML stuff, nothing special). So I have created a standard MVC controller with an action like so (and the Index.cshtml view is in the correct Views folder):

```
public class NotificationsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this action never gets run (I have a breakpoint).

**What I have tried to identify the problem**

Now I get at this point, it could be loads of different things, so here is what I have tried so far to debug the issue:

When I access the URL in a browser (e.g. `http://localhost:59461/Notifications`), I get:

> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

At first I thought maybe this is a routing issue, however in VS 2017 you can see that a request has failed for this action:

[image]

So surely the routing must be working correctly? Unfortunately, clicking the requests only confirms the 500 error and doesn't give any more information about the problem.

The only additional information I can find is in the Windows Event Viewer, in which I get the following error:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/PROJECTNAME' with physical root 'C:\PATH TO PROJECT FOLDER\' failed to start process with commandline '%LAUNCHER_PATH% %LAUNCHER_ARGS%', ErrorCode = '0x80070002 : 0.

But I have researched that error a lot and am yet to find a suitable solution or explanation for my problem.

I have also tried adding `Application_Error` but that isn't throwing any exceptions either.

At this point I don't know how to work out the cause of the problem. The only thing I can think of is that I need to configure something specifically to allow Web API projects to work with MVC controllers, but I can't find anything on that either.

What can I do to debug this problem correctly, and find the cause?

Comment: No, you don't need "special" configuration to run them together. You just need to make sure the routing doesn't conflict. Sounds like you need to pay attention to the `Application_Error` event and add proper logging to your application.

Comment: If you just want a static html page, just drop an html file in the root or wherever you want.  Since WebApi is still asp.net, it will server up the page without a problem.  no need to bring in mvc if you just want a static page.

Comment: @mason: I do have exception handling configured and it isn't catching anything (it works great for normal code exceptions). And just to be sure that isn't causing problems, I have just removed that completely and the problem is exactly the same still. Shouldn't running this with VS show me any exception that occur during execution?

Comment: @Fran: Sorry, the static HTML is just 'for now' as I don't want to over complicate it at the moment until it is working. I will want to make use of the razor view engine at some point later on

Comment: Are you using URL Rewrite?

Comment: You really need to create an [MCVE]. I'd start from the ground up. Do a new web application, and then start copying over functionality from old application. Test it at each step. You'll be able to figure it out quickly that way.

Comment: @mason: Yeah I hear what you are saying, problem is I do have a different test project that DOES work and I have been trying to compare all the configuration stuff and still can't find any mismatch. BTW, I have just added `Application_Error` and I get a different error on start up: `"The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."` I will update the question now, but do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Just some thoughts: Do you have a `HomeController` with an `Index` action? I'm thinking about the "The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController." error.
Also - and I know you're not using Kestrel - have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992280/http-error-500-localhost-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-request#42000680
Can you compare the IISExpress setup between your working test project and this broken one?

Comment: @SteGriffiths: No I don't have a Home controller. I think that error is misleading because VS automatically tries to navigate to `http://localhost:59461/` and it's that request that is throwing that error, and I don't expect that request to work anyway. Calling `http://localhost:59461/Notifications` does not throw an error in Application_Error. I will have a look at the question you linked

Comment: Check the IIS Express configurations (C: \ Users \ me \ Documents \ IISExpress \ config) and verify in the applicationhost.config file the mapping of the localhost routes, maybe it is pointing to another project.

Comment: @Makito: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't see anything that looks problematic. There are references to a few other projects, but no references to this project and no reference to port `59461` anywhere either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urgh... so I solved the problem...

After stumbling across [this post](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2041), there is a suggestion to delete the **.vs** folder in the Visual Studio solution folder. After doing this, and rebuilding the solution, it started working.

No idea what is in that folder that causes this problem exactly though, maybe something got corrupted or some sort of caching conflict, who knows...